# Багряний і пурпурний/пурпуровий. Один колір чи два різних?

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами

Пошук у ґуґлі видає два різних кольори:

1. [Багряний](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Ttg6XfeeJ_6GwPAPxOKvqAU&q=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%80&oq=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%80&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30.2386.3231..3960...0.0..0.199.672.3j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i67.pvT2bqy94WU&ved=0ahUKEwj3_de4stLjAhV-AxAIHUTxC1UQ4dUDCAo&uact=5).
2. [Пурпуровий](https://www.google.com/search?ei=vdg6XZnMKKaKmwXq-6iACw&q=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%80&oq=%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%80&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0l2j0i30j0i5i30l3.17268.19594..19842...2.0..1.238.1126.10j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i13j0i7i30j0i8i7i30j35i304i39.by6v8rYT8BY&ved=0ahUKEwjZntDtstLjAhUmxaYKHeo9CrAQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)

Але СУМ-11 ставить їх синонімами:

> Пурпурний:
>
> 2. Який має колір пурпуру; темно-червоний або яскраво-червоний **з фіолетовим відтінком**; *багряний*.
>
> Багряний:
>
> Густо-червоний, *пурпуровий*.

Як на мене, ці кольори відрізняються через фіолетовий відтінок, який є у пурпурового, але якого немає у багряного, але чому ж тоді СУМ-11 ставить їх синонімами? Бо це близькі кольори? Мені здається, це заплутує. Я навіть [бачив](http://linguisto.epizy.com/dict/en.php) у деяких перекладах "purple" перекладений як "багряний". Думаю, це не альтернативний, а хибний переклад.

Може, я неправий?

Answer (score 7):

Справді, один і той же колір можна назвати як *"багряним"*, так і *"пурпурним"* чи *"пурпуровим"*.

До прикладу, **Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови** (подібно до СУМ-11) сприймає слова *"багряний"* і *"пурпуровий"* (та подібні) як синоніми:

[Багряний](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53393/827655.html):

> Густо-червоний, **пурпуровий**.

[Багровий](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53393/827649.html):

> Густо-червоний. || Густо-червоний з легким синюватим відтінком.

[Багрянець](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53393/827654.html):

> Густо-червоний, **пурпуровий** колір.

[Пурпурний](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/969649.html):

> 1. Прикм. до пурпур 1). Пурпурний колір. || Пофарбований пурпуром (про тканину, одяг та інші речі).
> 2. Який має колір пурпуру; темно-червоний або яскраво-червоний з фіолетовим відтінком; **багряний**.

[Пурпуровий](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/969651.html):

> Те саме, що пурпурний.

[Пурпур](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/969644.html):

> 1. Фарбувальна речовина червоно-фіолетового кольору, яку добували в давні часи з залоз морського молюска.
> 2. Стародавня дорога тканина, пофарбована цією речовиною, а також одяг та інші речі з цієї тканини.
> 3. Темно-червоний або яскраво-червоний колір із фіолетовим відтінком; **багрянець**.

Мабуть, схожими за значенням їх сприймала і [Леся Українка](https://www.l-ukrainka.name/uk/Verses/Vidguky/Legendy/Legendy.html):

> Ті легенди червоніють,
>
> наче пишна **багряниця**,
>
> наче **пурпур** благородний,
>
> від крові людей невинних.

Якщо зазирнути в **Українську малу енциклопедію** проф. Онацького, знаходимо таке визначення [багряниці](http://encyclopedia.kiev.ua/vydaniya/files/use/first_book/part1.pdf):

> одяг із дорогоцінної тканини, пофарбованої в **пурпурову**, чи багряну, барву, що добувалася з багровця - морської черепашки. [...]

[Пурпур](http://encyclopedia.kiev.ua/vydaniya/files/use/third_book/part1.pdf) там означає:

> кармазин, фіолетово-червона барва, ознака царської влади вдавнину. [...] Пурпур колись добували з морських слимаків та кошенілі, тепер виробляють його хемічно. Див. **БАГРЯНИЦЯ**.

Виходить, походження слів "багряний" і "пурпурний" різне, але вони справді можуть означати схожі кольори.

Насправді, цю тему можна ще довго досліджувати) Наприклад, у статті [Tyrian purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_purple) англійської Вікіпедії є таке фото:

[image]

Наскільки я розумію, це відтінки пурпуру, який можна отримати з різних видів морських слимаків. Нижню тканину (густо-червону), мабуть, цілком можна назвати "багряною".

Загалом, складається враження, що фіолетовий відтінок може бути як у *пурпурного*, так і у *багряного* кольору. Але й "густо-червоним" (без фіолетового відтінку) теж можна назвати як *багряний*, так і *пурпурний*.

Можливо хтось зробить інші висновки, або спробує розібратися в темі глибше)

Comment: дякую за дослідження, я спробую його детально прочитати й розібрати пізніше.

Comment: @P.Vowk, у мене теж, до речі, є відповідь (чи радше доповнення). (Тільки там більше з фізичного й етимологічного боків.) Сподіваюся, зможу скоро її написати.

Comment: @Sasha чекатиму.

Answer (score 0):

## Коротко

**Можна перекладати як *багряний***. Але якщо точніше і технічніше, то до уваги **червонофіялковий**. Слово *purple* міняло своє значення, через що можливі проблеми.

## Довго

### Головне джерело

[Англійсько-український словник назв кольорів і кольорознавства](//diasporiana.org.ua/slovniki-dovidniki/vovk-a-anglijsko-ukrayinskyj-slovnyk-nazv-koloriv-i-koloroznavstva/) ([Анатоль Вовк](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), редактор Богдан Струмінський), 1986 рік.

### Витяги

> Англійська назва кольору purple стосується широкого засягу барв. Давніше ця назва означала інтенсивний або яскравий червоний колір, згодом — деякі його відтінки, а тепер це слово має в пояснювальних словниках два різні значення. У ширшому, більше популярному сенсі «purple» — це будь-який колір у колі барв між синім і червоним, включаючи і фіялковий (В-13, В-16). У другому, вужчому значенні «purple» — це проміжний колір між фіялковим і червоним (В-1). Цього вужчого значення вживає саме система UCL. Із вищенаведених українських відповідників для purple ні одна назва не має засягу цього вужчого сенсу англійського терміна. Усі ті пʼять слів пояснено в *Словнику української мови* (А-5) як темно — чи густочервониби з синявим чи фіолетовавим відтінком. Тому ми були змушені перекласти назву purple українською назвою **червонофіялковий**, яка точно дає обсяг цього кольору в УНК.

> **purple** n. a. пурпу́р, багря́нець, багрець, багра, «фіялкова червінь»; пурпуро́вий, пурпу́рний, багряний, багровий (початково к. тирійського пурпуру з Фінікії) о: к. посередній між червоним і синім [1, 3]; к. посередній між червоним і фія́лко́вим [2, 4], черво̀нофія́лковий (у цьому словнику); сѝнявочервоний а. кардина́льський яскравочервоний [3]; темночервоний а. яскра̀вочерво́ний з фіоле́товим відтінком [С, для «пурпурний»].

#### Домовленості

« » — слова в таких лапках є дослівним перекладом англійської назви, невживаним, одначе, у мововжитку

##### Значення кодів джерел у реєстрі словника

[1] Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 17)
[2] American Heritage Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 1)
[3] Oxford Illustrated Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 13)
[4] Dictionary of Color Names (Підрозділ В. ч. 10)
[С] **Словник української мови**, 11 томів (Підрозділ А. ч. 5)

##### Джерела і література до теми

А. Загальні і галузеві українські словники

5. Білодід, І. К., гол. ред. **Словник української мови**, в 11-ти томах. АН УРСР, Київ, в-во «Наукова думка», 1970-1980.

В. Джерела для англійської мови

1. *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, ed. W. Morris. Boston, New York: American Heritage Publishing Co. and Houghton Mifflin Co., 1969.

13. *Oxford Illustrated Dictionary*, ed. J. Coulson et al. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1962.

16. Verity Enid. *Color observed*. New York…: Van Nostrand Reinhold, 1980.